# configuring autoloader in bootstrap failed

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I followed a tutorial just to get deeper in the form topic.

I built a Form class: application/forms/BugReportForm.php 
I added to my bootstrap.php (before it was unused)

```
protected function _InitAutoload()
    {

        $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
        $resourceLoader= new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
            'basePath'  =>  APPLICATION_PATH,
            'namespace' =>  '',
            'resourceTypes' =>  array(
            'form'  =>  array(
            'path'  => 'forms/',
            'namespace' => 'Form_',
            )
            ),
        ));
        //return it ao sthat istcan stored in the bootstrap
        return $autoLoader;
    }
```

I built also my forms/BugReportForm.php

My BugController.php looks like this:

```
<?php

class BugController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    }

    public function submitAction()
    {
        $frmBugReport = new Form_BugReport();
        $frmBugReport = setAction('/bug/submit');
        $frmBugReport = setMethod('post');
        $this->view->form = $frmBugReport;
    }
```

my application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0

includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0
phpSettings.date.timezone = "Europe/Berlin"

resources.db.adapter = PDO_MYSQL
resources.db.params.host = localhost
resources.db.params.username = root
resources.db.params.password = 
resources.db.params.dbname = TQM
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
resources.db.params.driver_options.1002 = "SET NAMES utf8"


resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"

resources.view.doctype = "XHTML1_STRICT"
```

I get this Error : Class 'Form_BugReportForm' not found in ....

What ist wrong, I think the bootstrap doesn´t work or the namespace ist not known?

Folderstructure
[image: Folderstructure]

[image: folder forms]

and at the moment I don´t use virtual hosts.

errors after changing my class call in $frmBugReport = new Application_Form_BugReportForm();

[image: fatal error output]

hier for example another very small form

```
<?php
// Formular wird angezeigt bei neue Ebene 1 und editieren
class Application_Form_Hierarchie extends Zend_Form
{

    public function init()
    {
        $this->setName('Ebene1');
        $this->setAttrib('enctype', 'multipart/form-data');         //Formular wird für Dateiuploads verwendet
        $nr = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('nr');
        $nr->addFilter('Int');
        $ebene1 = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('ebene1');
            $ebene1->setLabel('Ebene1')
            ->setRequired(true)
            ->addFilter('StripTags')
            ->addFilter('StringTrim')
            ->addValidator('NotEmpty');




        $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setAttrib('nr', 'submitbutton');
        $this->addElements(array($nr, $ebene1, $submit));       //, $imagepreview
    }

}

?>
```

and hier the action (add) from the Controller:

```
$form = new Application_Form_Hierarchie();
```

I tried the other posibility (it is from a book tutorial) to learn how to use own formclasses. I think I should give up with the turorial and go back to the simple way.

Comment: Please provide code for BugReportForm.

Comment: thanks for the remark,here the head of the class:
class Form_BugReportForm extends Zend_Form
/forms/BugReportForm.php

Comment: here is the error:
 Fatal error: Class 'Form_BugReportForm' not found in C:\wamp\www\cheyenne\application\controllers\BugController.php on line 15
Line 15 in the controller: $frmBugReport = new Form_BugReportForm();

Comment: Could you give the folder structure of your application ? And are you using virtualhost or not ?

Comment: yes I've put in the posting

Comment: did the other forms work ?

Comment: yes the other forms are working well, the difference is, this time I wanted to create my own Form class, so I tried how they did in the tutorial.

Comment: Try this within your controller action : `$frmBugReport = new Application_Form_BugReportForm();` and turn on your error reporting in `application.ini` file like this by adding this : `resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1`

Comment: interesting, first after trying your proposal, I got some errors in my form class, after fixing it, I got another fatal error:
Fatal error: Class 'Application_Form_BugReportForm' not found in C:\wamp\www\cheyenne\application\controllers\BugController.php on line 15

Comment: What sort of error you've got when you tried it ?

Comment: I just uploaded a picture

Comment: I mean the erros that you have fixed

Comment: just some syntax errors like writing = > istead of =>

Comment: Try to rename the form class to `Application_Form_BugFormReport`

Comment: I´ve tried already and I get the same error message with the new name. It´s no need to rename the BugReportForm.php also?

Comment: I'm confused. What's the difference with the other forms ?

Comment: I just posted one of the other formclasses

Comment: I see. Please can I have a link to the tutorial you've followed ?

Comment: it's an ebook Pro Zend Framework Techniques by Forrest Lyman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem probably comes from the wrong class name specified in your application. Be sure to follow these rules while working with zend from and models, and you'll be fine :

**Bootstrap.php file:**

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap{

       protected function _initAutoload(){
        $resourceLoader= new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(
                                     array(   
                                          'namespace' => '',   
                                          'basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH
                                          ));
       $resourceLoader->addResourceType('model', 'models/', 'Model');
       $resourceLoader->addResourceType('form', 'forms/', 'Form');   
       return $resourceLoader;
      }
 }
```

**Zend_Form directory and file names :**

1. The Default name space in zend framework for `Zend_Form` is **Form** and it will pointing to folder named as **forms**.
2. Your form class name should start with namespace as `Form_`
3. Create a file inside the forms directory as `yourFormName.php` . This will be your Form class file.
4. Inside `yourFormName.php` create a class as `Form_yourFormName.php`

**yourFormName.php :**

```
class Form_yourFormName extends Zend_Form
  {
  public function init()
  {
      //your form codes goes here like creating form elements
  }
 }
```

Then in your controller get a instance of your defined form class :

```
class YourController extends Zend_Controller_Action
 {
public function indexAction()
{
   $form = new Form_yourFormName();
   $this->view->form = $form;
}
}
```

**EDIT :** For your case it should be :

```
    $frmBugReport = new Form_BugReportForm();
```

Not :

```
   $frmBugReport = new Form_BugReport();
```

Comment: thanks, here the head of my formclass: class Form_BugReportForm extends Zend_Form
The name of the file is:/forms/BugReportForm.php 
Here instanciating the Objekt: $frmBugReport = new Form_BugReportForm();
Thanks for another idea

Comment: I checked again every name, but I didn´t see the error